# NodeJs get result from previous chain as async and pass it to nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js

after uploading image from client as Base64 to server i want to

1. save file to disk
2. get result of save (first chain) and pass it to next chain
3. check result on next function on `that()`, if its true, update database and return result
4. check result and print

this below code is my implementing chain, but that seems is not correct, because i cant get result from first chain as `savePhotoOnDisk`

```
savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath)
    .then(updateUserPhoto(result, userId, filename))
    .then(FUNCTION(GET RESULT)
    .then(OTHER FUNCTION() {
        PRINT RESULT
    });
```

or this chain:

```
savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath)
    .then(function(result){
        updateUserPhoto(result, userId, filename);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        OTHER FUNCTION
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        PRINT RESULT
    })
    .catch(function (v) {
        log.info('error chaining');
    });

function updateUserPhoto(result, userId, filename) {
    log.info(result);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var query = "UPDATE users SET userPhoto = ? WHERE userId = ? ;";
        connection.query(query, [filename, userId], function (err, results) {
            if (err) return reject(false);

            if (results.length === 0) return reject(false);

            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}
function savePhotoOnDisk(filename) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        require("fs").writeFile(filename, base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
            log.info(err + "upload");
            if (err == null)
                resolve(true);
            else
                reject(false);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm newbie to use this nodejs feature, please help to fix that, Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath)
    .then(function (result) {
        return {success:result};
    })
    .then(updateUserPhoto(success, userId, filename),function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(function (v) {
        log.info('error chaining');
    });
```

Comment: Is your code not writing to the file? Or is it that your is not getting executed past that? As far as I can tell your code is probably not writing into DB. The reason is because you are calling `updateUserPhoto` inside a promise which is async and returns a promise.

Comment: @Putty my problem is implementing this chain. save on disk and return result to next function, if passed result is true then update user on database then return result and check that last chain to print result

Comment: I do not think that will work.I do not see the point of passing result in the first place. If your promise resolves then the next statement in then is called with whatever you return. If you reject then the catch function is called. And do notcall the updateUserPhoto or you should return a function with updateUserPhoto

Comment: @Putty could you fix my code?

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your request. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You are calling promise inside promise which is the issue. Try changing the code to something like this.

```
     savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath)
      .then(function () {
       return {
          userId : userId,
          fileName : fileName
       }
     })
    .then(updateUserPhoto)
    .then(FUNCTION(GET RESULT)
    .then(OTHER FUNCTION() {
        PRINT RESULT
    });

    function updateUserPhoto(data) {
        var userId = data.userId;
        var fileName = data.fileName;
        // call your function as it was earlier.
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath)
    .then(updateUserPhoto.bind(true, userId, filename))
    .then(function (result) {
        OTHER FUNCTION
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        PRINT RESULT
    })
    .catch(function (v) {
        log.info('error chaining');
    });

function updateUserPhoto(result, userId, filename) {
    log.info(result);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var query = "UPDATE users SET userPhoto = ? WHERE userId = ? ;";
        connection.query(query, [filename, userId], function (err, results) {
            if (err) return reject(false);

            if (results.length === 0) return reject(false);

            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}
function savePhotoOnDisk(filename) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        require("fs").writeFile(filename, base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
            log.info(err + "upload");
            if (err == null)
                resolve(true);
            else
                reject(false);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: my post updated with your solution, could you review again? Thanks

Comment: I updated the solution trying not to modify your functions

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Resolved**

this is my correct code to create simple chain and pass result to next method as `Promise`

I hope to helpful this post

```
savePhotoOnDisk(filenameWithPath, photoBase64).then(function (result) {
    return updateUserPhoto(result, userId, filename);
}).then(function (save) {
    if (save)
        socket.emit('uploadUserPhoto', true);
    else
        socket.emit('uploadUserPhoto', false);
}).catch(function (v) {
    socket.emit('uploadUserPhoto', false);
});
```